# Android Binding Library for Paytm SDK

Tags: xml, xamarin, jar, xamarin.android, paytm

Unable to make the binding library for Paytm SDk.I have followed the xamarin developer document  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/ .But, when I build the project it throws the following error

**

> **1>JARTOXML : error J2X0001: Couldn't open java archive : java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file 1>JARTOXML :
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning : ignoring option UseSplitVerifier;
>   support was removed in 8.0****

**

I am not sure whether it is there any problem with my build properties or Paytm SDK. If it is related to SDK,I have no other options,but leave this project.

Comment: Look at the `--jar=` option in the build output and the see if you have included any files that are not `.jars`

Comment: @SushiHangover I have included only one .jar file.I do not quite understand --jar= option.

Comment: In the build output for the cmd, you will find all the cmd line arguments that are being used, check  each one of the `--jar=` parameters. Make sure that only the `.jar` is being used, usually that error means that you are trying to unzip something other that a valid `jar` file (i.e. a txt, xml,..... file, or that the war file itself is corrupt (can you manually unzip the jar?)

Comment: @SushiHangover  I was able to unzip the files and had a look of each class file.It's opening without any issues in my android studio.